# Controller not a function, got undefined, while defining controllers globally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am writing a sample application using angularjs. i got an error mentioned below on chrome browser.

Error is

> Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.17/ng/areq?p0=ContactController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Which renders as

> Argument 'ContactController' is not a function, got undefined

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="../angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ContactController($scope) {
            $scope.contacts = ["abcd@gmail.com", "abcd@yahoo.co.in"];

            $scope.add = function() {
                $scope.contacts.push($scope.newcontact);
                $scope.newcontact = "";                 
            };
        }    
    </script>    
</head>

<body>    
    <h1>  modules sample </h1>

    <div ng-controller="ContactController">
        Email:<input type="text" ng-model="newcontact">
        <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>

        <h2> Contacts </h2>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts"> {{contact}} </li>
        </ul>    
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 169, accepted):

With Angular 1.3+ you can no longer use global controller declaration on the global scope (Without explicit registration). You would need to register the controller using `module.controller` syntax.

Example:-

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('ContactController', ['$scope', function ContactController($scope) {
        $scope.contacts = ["abcd@gmail.com", "abcd@yahoo.co.in"];

        $scope.add = function() {
            $scope.contacts.push($scope.newcontact);
            $scope.newcontact = "";

        };
    }]);
```

or

```
function ContactController($scope) {
    $scope.contacts = ["abcd@gmail.com", "abcd@yahoo.co.in"];

    $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.contacts.push($scope.newcontact);
        $scope.newcontact = "";
    };
}
ContactController.$inject = ['$scope'];
angular.module('app', []).controller('ContactController', ContactController);
```

It is a breaking change but it [can be turned off to use globals by using `allowGlobals`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider).

Example:-

```
angular.module('app')
    .config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
        $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
    }]);
```

Here is the comment from Angular source:-

> - check if a controller with given name is registered via `$controllerProvider`
> - check if evaluating the string on the current scope returns a constructor
> - if $controllerProvider#allowGlobals, check `window[constructor]` on the global `window` object (not recommended)

```
 .....

expression = controllers.hasOwnProperty(constructor)
            ? controllers[constructor]
            : getter(locals.$scope, constructor, true) ||
                (globals ? getter($window, constructor, true) : undefined);
```

Some additional checks:-

- Do Make sure to put the appname in `ng-app` directive on your angular root element (eg:- `html`) as well. Example:- ng-app="myApp"
- If everything is fine and you are still getting the issue do remember to make sure you have the right file included in the scripts.
- You have not defined the same module twice in different places which results in any entities defined previously on the same module to be cleared out, Example `angular.module('app',[]).controller(..` and again in another place `angular.module('app',[]).service(..` (with both the scripts included of course) can cause the previously registered controller on the module `app` to be cleared out with the second recreation of module.

Comment: How to check this as suggested? check if a controller with given name is registered via $controllerProvider

Comment: app.register.controller('TheController', TheController); did the trick for me.

Answer (score 33):

I got this problem because I had wrapped a controller-definition file in a closure:

```
(function() {
   ...stuff...
});
```

But I had forgotten to actually invoke that closure to execute that definition code and actually tell Javascript my controller existed. I.e., the above needs to be:

```
(function() {
   ...stuff...
})();
```

**Note the () at the end.**

Comment: +1 Interestingly, it seems like visual studio sometimes automatically removes the invocation. I copied an existing js file containing this code; the original had the invocation, the copied file did not.

Answer (score 16):

I am a beginner with Angular and I did the basic mistake of not including the app name in the angular root element. So, changing the code from

```
<html data-ng-app>
```

to

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
```

worked for me. @PSL, has covered this already in his answer above.

Answer (score 8):

I had this error because I didn't understand the difference between `angular.module('myApp', [])` and `angular.module('myApp')`.

This **creates** the module 'myApp' and overwrites any existing module named 'myApp':

`angular.module('myApp', [])`

This **retrieves** an existing module 'myApp':

`angular.module('myApp')`

I had been overwriting my module in another file, using the first call above which created another module instead of retrieving as I expected.

More detail here:  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: In my case, I added the module, I added the controller, but I forgot to add the module in the list of module for the app. ` angular.module("app", [HEREYOURMODULE] ...`

Answer (score 3):

I just migrate to angular 1.3.3 and I found that If I had multiple controllers in different files when app is override and I lost first declared containers.

I don't know if is a good practise, but maybe can be helpful for another one.

```
var app = app;
if(!app) {
    app = angular.module('web', ['ui.bootstrap']);
}
app.controller('SearchCtrl', SearchCtrl);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem when I accidentally redeclared `myApp`:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[...]);
myApp.controller('Controller1', ...);

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[...]);
myApp.controller('Controller2', ...);
```

After the redeclare, `Controller1` stops working and raises the OP error.

Answer (score 2):

Really great advise, except that the **SAME** error CAN occur simply by missing the critical script include on your root page

example:

page:  index.html

```
   np-app="saleApp"
```

**Missing**

```
<script src="./ordersController.js"></script>
```

When a Route is told what controller and view to serve up:

```
 .when('/orders/:customerId', {
     controller: 'OrdersController',
     templateUrl: 'views/orders.html'
 })
```

So essential the undefined controller issue CAN occur in this accidental mistake of not even referencing the controller!

Answer (score 0):

This error might also occur when you have a large project with many modules.
Make sure that the app (module) used in you angular file is the same that you use in your template, in this example "**thisApp**".

app.js

```
angular
.module('thisApp', [])
    .controller('ContactController', ['$scope', function ContactController($scope) {
        $scope.contacts = ["abcd@gmail.com", "abcd@yahoo.co.in"];

        $scope.add = function() {
            $scope.contacts.push($scope.newcontact);
            $scope.newcontact = "";

        };
    }]);
```

index.html

```
  <html>
    <body ng-app='thisApp' ng-controller='ContactController>
         ...
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails and you are using Gulp or something similar...just rerun it!

I wasted 30mins quadruple checking everything when all it needed was a swift kick in the pants.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using routes (high probability) and your config has a reference to a controller in a module that's not declared as dependency then initialisation might fail too.

E.g assuming you've configured ngRoute for your app, like

```
angular.module('yourModule',['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) { ... });
```

Be careful in the block that declares the routes,

```
.when('/resourcePath', { 
templateUrl: 'resource.html',
controller: 'secondModuleController' //lives in secondModule
});
```

Declare `secondModule` as a dependency after 'ngRoute' should resolve the issue. I know I had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I was using an older version of angular that wasn't compatible with my code.

Answer (score 0):

These errors occurred, in my case, preceeded by syntax errors at list.find() fuction; 'find' method of a list not recognized by IE11, so has to replace by Filter method, which works for both IE11 and chrome. 
refer https://github.com/flrs/visavail/issues/19

Answer (score 0):

This error, in my case, preceded by syntax error at find method of a list in IE11. so replaced find method by filter method as suggested https://github.com/flrs/visavail/issues/19

then above controller not defined error resolved.

Answer (score -3):

I got the same error while following an old tutorial with (not old enough) AngularJS 1.4.3. By far the simplest solution is to edit *angular.js* source from

```
function $ControllerProvider() {
  var controllers = {},
      globals = false;
```

to

```
function $ControllerProvider() {
  var controllers = {},
      globals = true;
```

and just follow the tutorial as-is, and the deprecated global functions just work as controllers.

Comment: This is bad practice. As mentioned in PSL's answer, you can do this way: `angular.module('app')
    .config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
        $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
    }]);`

Comment: -1. This is also a great way to ensure that (a) you overwrite this as soon as you upgrade, which will generate needless (and incorrect) reports that "upgrading 1.4.3 to 1.4.4 broke my application!" and/or (b) you don't upgrade your app because "it's hard."