# Angular function constructor in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In normal JS I can do this:

```
function Droppable() {
    this.relevant = true;
    this.uuid = generateUUID();
};

var generateUUID = function() {
   return '12345';
}


console.log(new Droppable); // returns Droppable {relevant: true, uuid: "12345"}
```

But in Angular I have this:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    function Droppable() {
        this.relevant = true;
        this.uuid = generateUUID();
    }

    var generateUUID = function() {
        return '12345';
    }

    // initalize droppable areas
    $scope.region1 = [new Droppable];
    $scope.region2 = [new Droppable];
    $scope.region3 = [new Droppable];

}]);
```

I am trying to make 3 droppable areas all with a UUID.

But when I do this I get **'undefined is not a function'** referring to the line `this.uuid = generateUUID();` in `function Droppable() {...}`

Why is that?

Comment: Most Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111831/controller-not-a-function-got-undefined-while-defining-controllers-globally/25111942#25111942 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330193/angularjs-asp-net-mvc-controller-undefined/25330617#25330617

Comment: I have just tried your code inside an angular controller and I got it working as expected. Do you know which version of angular you are using? I have tested in angular 1.2.15.

Comment: @PSL I don't think it is either one of those. I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Kamrul I am using 1.2.16.

Comment: It must be a typo, app name not specified, controller registration not loaded etc.. then? Show us an example to replicate the issue. The code you have provided does not tell much.

Comment: @PSL I don't think that other question is the answer in my case because I have been working on this app for about a month now and am just running into this problem today.  It is not a day one set up problem.  All the other functionality in my controller is working just fine.

Comment: OK more code. Now it makes sense.. Are you sure you are instantiating `Droppable` only after `var generateUUID=..` Change `var generateUUID = function() {` to `function generateUUID () {` and see what happens. http://plnkr.co/edit/NYrVx6?p=preview Or probably a [typical case of this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting) ?

Comment: @BigHeadCreations Sure i l add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment to answer. Your issue is due to the variable holding the function expression is being used before it has been assigned, in which case the variable `generateUUID` is not defined yet.

```
var generateUUID = function() {
    return '12345';
}
```

One way to fix it, is to turn it to function declaration so that it is automatically hoisted to the top of the scope.

```
function generateUUID () {
        return '12345';
 }
```

or define the variable `generateUUID` to a function reference before its possible usage.

```
//Some variable declarations, start of the scope
var generateUUID = function() {
    return '12345';
}

function Droppable() {
    this.relevant = true;
    this.uuid = generateUUID();
}
```

When you do:-

```
.... Some Code ....


var generateUUID = function() {
        return '12345';
    }

.... Some Code ...
```

it is same as:-

```
var generateUUID;
.... Some Code ....
//Any usage of this till here will cause the error that you are facing, since there is no value assigned to generateUUID yet
generateUUID = function() {
            return '12345';
  }

.... Some Code ...
```

**Some reference:- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475420/why-the-for-loop-counter-doesnt-get-destroyed-after-exiting-the-loop-in-javascr/17475462#17475462)**

and a **[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bhgzlg?p=preview)**

*Note:- This issue should not happen in your example because you are invoking the constructor after it (`generateUUID`) has been assigned with value, probably a different usecase (which is not present in the question) might be having this issue.*

Answer (score 1):

```
function Droppable() {
  this.relevant = true;
  this.uuid = generateUUID();
}
var generateUUID = function() {
  return '12345';
}
```

Okay, this is not a problem about AngularJS but it is more about Javascript.
Read up on Javascript variable hoisting.
When you declare a function using the var keyword, there are two things happens: You create a variable, and then assign a variable to it. Because of javascript hoisting, variable declaration (var generateUUID) will be hoisted to the top, where the declaration happens later where you wrote it.

```
var generateUUID;   //undefined
function Droppable() {
  this.relevant = true;
  this.uuid = generateUUID(); //you are invoking undefined here.
}
generateUUID = function() {
  return '12345';
}
```

the right way to do it would be:

```
function Droppable() {
  this.relevant = true;
  this.uuid = generateUUID();
}
function GenerateUUID() {
  return '12345';
}
```

Here, because you use by "function GenerateUUID()", the **whole thing** get hoisted to the top instead of only just the variable

Answer (score 1):

Giving some quick examples

```
function Droppable() {
    this.relevant = true;
    this.uuid = generateUUID();
}

// this will throw an error because you are calling generateUUID before it initialize
console.log(new Droppable);

var generateUUID = function() {
   return '12345';
}

// this will give you actuall output what you wanted
console.log(new Droppable);
```

So when you will call function generateUUID before calling Droppable it will work. Like this -

```
// initializes
var generateUUID = function() {
    return '12345';
}

// initializes
function Droppable() {
    this.relevant = true;
    this.uuid = generateUUID();
}

// this will work as expected
console.log(new Droppable);
```

In JavaScript you can define function in two method

```
var varibaleName = function(){

}
```

and

```
function variableName(){

}
```

There is a significant differences. When you are declaring a function with a variable then before call that function that variable need to register.

if you call like this -

```
varibaleName();
var varibaleName = function(){

}
```

this will give you an error.

But if you call like this it will work -

```
varibaleName();
function varibaleName (){

}
```

So this should work too -

```
function Droppable() {
    this.relevant = true;
    this.uuid = generateUUID();
}

// this will work as expected
console.log(new Droppable);


function generateUUID() {
    return '12345';
}
```

Hope this make sense.

However in angular this will work -

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){

    function Droppable() {
        this.relevant = true;
        this.uuid = generateUUID();
    }

    var generateUUID = function() {
        return '12345';
    }

    // initalize droppable areas
    $scope.region1 = [new Droppable];
    $scope.region2 = [new Droppable];
    $scope.region3 = [new Droppable];

    console.log( $scope.region1 );
});
```

But best practice is -

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){

    // you can call this before Droppable or after
    $scope.generateUUID = function() {
        return '12345';
    }

    $scope.Droppable = function () {
        this.relevant = true;
        this.uuid = $scope.generateUUID();
    }

    // initalize droppable areas
    $scope.region1 = [new $scope.Droppable];

    console.log( $scope.region1 );
});
```

Why i am calling those with `$scope.` prefix, because later you may need to talk between controller to controllers even in directives!

Happy coding and happy prototyping! How this helps you to understand how things are working.

Comment: Yep, that was my problem exactly.  Thanks for going into an explanation of why. However PSL beat you to the answer :)

Comment: @BigHeadCreations no matter who beats whom. You've got your solution that what we need :) we are happy to help you!

Comment: upvoted your comment for proper grammar - 'who beats whom' - impressive :)  @HADI