# Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my HTML and JS File

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">

<head>
  <!--Works with latest Stable Build-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

  <!--Does not work with Latest Beta-->
  <!--UNCOMMENT ME! <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.min.js"></script>-->


  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <h1>Angular Playground</h1>
  {{message}}
  <br />Total Length: {{message.length}}
</body>

</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT FILE

```
var MainController = function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Hello, Michael";
};
```

If I use the latest stable build, then I get the following result (which is obviously correct):

> Angular Playground
>
> Hello, Michael  Total Length: 14

However, if I use Beta 18, then I get the following error:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined

and the page returns the following:

> Angular Playground #2
>
> {{message}}  Total Length: {{message.length}}

Any idea, what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you check this answer? Probably same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111831/controller-not-a-function-got-undefined-while-defining-controllers-globally/25111942#25111942

Comment: The above comment is the correct answer. I would vote on it if it was posted that way.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

With the latest versions of Angular (>1.3.0), you can't declare a global constructor function and use it with ng-controller.

A quick fix would be to create an angular module and add MainController as a controller.

Here I've wrapped MainController in an IIFE to prevent the function from being added as a global:

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module("appName", [])
        .controller("MainController", MainController);

    MainController.$inject = ["$scope"];

    function MainController($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Hello, Michael";
    };

})();
```

In your HTML, you'll need to add the name of the angular module to the ng-app directive:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="appName">

<head>
  <!--Works with latest Stable Build-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

  <!--Does not work with Latest Beta-->
  <!--UNCOMMENT ME! <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.min.js"></script>-->


  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <h1>Angular Playground</h1>
  {{message}}
  <br />Total Length: {{message.length}}
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Was about to throw a few punches until I saw this answer. The pluralsight Angular.js course uses an older version, where the global constructor was allowed. Had the exact same code (except forthe linked angular.js) and it just wouldn't work. This solved the problem.

Comment: Took me a few mins to notice the subtlety of the ng-app="app" tag on the html that relates to angular.module("app", ...

Thanks!