# Controller constructors in global scope are not working

Tags: angularjs

I've seen this basic AngularJS code in a tutorial video which gives the output as expected. But when I try the same code locally it does not work, it shows `{{message}}` as the output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{message}}</h1>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function HelloWorldCtrl($scope)
        {
            $scope.message = "First Run...";
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the console it shows an error,

```
Argument 'HelloWorldCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

> Error: [ng:areq]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/ng/areq?p0=HelloWorldCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Why this same code behaving differently in different environments?
Can someone point out what I'm missing here?

Comment: Is it possible that `Scripts/angular.min.js` doesn't exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controller not a function, got undefined, while defining controllers globally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111831/controller-not-a-function-got-undefined-while-defining-controllers-globally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is something changed in angular1.3.rc2! 
http://jsbin.com/sumifozawiji/1/edit

i got same error. 1.2.25 works:
http://jsbin.com/lanavuvaniva/1/edit

Comment: Yes, I have `angular1.3.rc2` in my project, with stable version it works fine, Thanks.... :)

Comment: This is not the proper answer, nothing is "broke" it is a change in the way they want declarations. The old way works if you do this...  see http://www.lcube.se/angular-js-controller-error-argument-is-not-a-function/ here is it working... http://jsbin.com/qificutuje/1/edit. That says you should be able to set a setting but I couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 1):

Since Angular v1.3.0-beta defining controller constructors in the global scope is **[no longer supported](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3f2232b5a181512fac23775b1df4a6ebda67d018)**.

Answer (score 0):

Angular will run, it will bootstrap automatically (because of the `ng-app` attribute) and expects to find a controller named `HelloWorldCtrl` (due to the `ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl"`). But this controller is defined *after* Angular, so it is not there at the moment of execution.

The simplest solution is to change the order of the scripts, i.e. put your code before Angular.