# Angular js Controller prints only the curly brackets

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am going over a tutorial on Angular JS, I have gone over the code several times and its exactly as the person types but get `{{name}}` and `{{age}}` in the browser.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? 
Another question that I have is that in one tutorial his html document has got the `head` and `body` tags in another its just the doctype, a link to angular and then he starts typing his code.

If this is a style, which one should I follow, shall i leave the body tag on or remove them?

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <input ng-model="name">
         <h1>{{name}}</h1>

         <h2>{{age}}</h2>

    </div>
    <script>
        var Ctrl = function($scope) {
            $scope.name = "James";
            $scope.age = "20";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You should include your opening html and body tags in the example, as the problem could lie there. For instance you need to have ng-app as an attribute in the html tag, I can't tell if you do without seeing the whole example

Comment: Check the browser console for errors, I suspect you haven't initialised the ng-app and associated the controller function with the app module.

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap your angular app, and register  your controller

```
 var app = angular.module('app',[]);
 app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
     $scope.name = 'james';
     $scope.age = 20;
});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    {{name}}<br />
     {{age}}
 </body>
```

Comment: Just as a side note, if you wish to validate the html, you will need to add 'data' ie ng-app would become data-ng-app, this is valid html5.

Answer (score 0):

Your tutorial seems a bit old.  Your code is *almost* valid for Angular 1.2+ (it won't run in 1.3+).  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25111942/16363) for details.

You do need to add an ng-app directive:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="Ctrl">
```

See example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RCTYA5KGSX133dWEbRDk?p=preview).

As @pixelbits says in his answer, though, you should do it the newer way.