# AngularJS: values of defined variables inside controller are not getting displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am learning angular.. I have tried to run a small example through pluralsight, but wasn't able to render correct output..
http://plnkr.co/edit/cYEDSW3FrAKeh1SBjUVN?p=preview
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{text}}</h1>

    <div>
      <div>First name: {{person.firstName}}</div>
      <div>Last name: {{person.lastName}}</div>
      <img ng-src="person.imageSrc" title="{{person.firstName}} {{person.lastName}}">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
var MainController = function($scope) {

  var person = {
    firstName: "Ajay",
    lastName: "Sattikar",
    imageSrc: "http://odetocode.com/Images/scott_allen_2.jpg"

  };

  $scope.text = "Hello Angular!";
  $scope.person = person;

};
```

I am not able to figure out why angular variables are getting displayed as normal text instead of its assigned value. Experts, kindly help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controller not a function, got undefined, while defining controllers globally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111831/controller-not-a-function-got-undefined-while-defining-controllers-globally)

Comment: It does not work because pluralsight demo version might be using older version of angular application.

Comment: That code is valid with older versions of angular, but since 1.3 you need to declare the module (see other responses). However try replacing the angular loaded by, let's say, 1.1.5 instead of 1.3.7 and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that need to be changed in your code

1. you need to create an angular module

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

2 add directive to html element

```
<html ng-app='app'>
```

3. need to register `MainController` against angular module like this:

```js
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {

  var person = {
    firstName: "Ajay",
    lastName: "Sattikar",
    imageSrc: "http://odetocode.com/Images/scott_allen_2.jpg"

  };

  $scope.text = "Hello Angular!";
  $scope.person = person;

});
```

Here is a working **demo** - http://plnkr.co/edit/i9N2OC75EGZwUTDcKtLB?p=preview

Comment: This works perfect. Thanks. However, one minor issue, the img src is showing as a "person.imageSrc" and not converting into the actual path (i.e. value of "person.imageSrc"), can you please assist?

Comment: great, if it helps solve your problem you can click the big tick to show other people the working solution. I will take a look at code now and see if I can see the problem

Comment: Got it.. I missed parenthesis.. {{..}}

Comment: great, another way that works is to use `<img ng-src="http://odetocode.com/{{person.imageSrc}}" ...>` and update your javascript accordingly, just whatever is best for your situation

Answer (score 0):

You missed a few steps:
1. Declaring your app

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
```

2. Declaring your controller inside your app module:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
 .controller('MainController', function($scope) {

     var person = {
         firstName: "Ajay",
         lastName: "Sattikar",
         imageSrc: "http://odetocode.com/Images/scott_allen_2.jpg"
     };

     $scope.text = "Hello Angular!";
     $scope.person = person;
})
```