# In angularjs, calling controller as constructor is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new to angularjs and i tried practicing some examples. In the below stated example I am trying to initialize a value and setting it in scope. it is working fine, if i initialize the controller and scope values as given in the commented lines . but instead of those commented lines of code, if i try to set a controller and initialize scope value , like a regular javascript constructor function, then my example is not working.. Please anyone kindly explain why it is not working ?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Practices</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

/*var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('HelloController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.value = "World";
}]);*/

var HelloController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.value = 'World';
    }
    </script> 
</head>
<body ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="HelloController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="value" placeholder="enter your name">
    <div>Hi {{value}} !! </div> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error you're getting ?

Comment: Go to the documentation of Angular. you need to learn..

Comment: With Angular 1.3 global controllers are not allowed by default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111831/controller-not-a-function-got-undefined-while-defining-controllers-globally

Comment: this is the error i am getting ..   Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/ng/areq?p0=WorldCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined