# Why this simple Angular.js example does not work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm reading **AngularJS** from *O'REILLY*, and i tried to see how angular works with an example but i can make it functional:

The *hello.html* :

```
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="HelloController">
      <p>{{ greeting.text }}, World</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the logic within the *controllers.js* :

```
function HelloController($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
}
```

but when i display the *hello.html* on the browser, i can see `{{ greeting.text }}, Hello`.

What is wrong here?

Comment: If you're using version 1.3+, you cannot by default use global functions as controllers. You should check your console for errors

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controller not a function, got undefined, while defining controllers globally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111831/controller-not-a-function-got-undefined-while-defining-controllers-globally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never defined a controller, you just defined a function that happened to have "controller" in the name.

Try initializing the app properly:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('HelloController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = {text: 'Hello'};
}]);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: That's not his issue, he should be able to do it without having to define it the way you have.

Comment: @YangLi not in 1.3 (by default). In any case, this question has already been answered (assuming this is the actual problem)