# why this angular file does not work?

Tags: angularjs

Why doesn't this code work? I am trying to find it during last four days...

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'mainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html ng-app>
    <head>
    <title> test angular html </title>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"> </script>
    <script>
    function mainCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.value = 100;
    } 
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <h1> {{value}} </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: which version ofangular do you use? you may need to declare you module (`angular.module(name, [])`) with the recent ones.

Comment: I am using 1.3.14.  below also didn't work.     angular.module("myapp", [])) {
        function mainCtrl($scope) {
                $scope.value = 100;
        }
}

Comment: you have to give you app a name with the ng-app and then in your javascript add angular.module('yourappname', [])

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controller not a function, got undefined, while defining controllers globally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111831/controller-not-a-function-got-undefined-while-defining-controllers-globally)

Comment: below is working.. thanks floribon! Is it mandatory to put them in module in the latest version???   <!doctype html>
<html ng-app= "myapp">
<head>
<title> test angular html </title>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"> </script>
<script>

angular.module("myapp", []).controller("mainCtrl",['$scope',
        function mainCtrl($scope) {
                $scope.value = 100;
        }]);
</script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<h1> {{value}} </h1>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 2):

When you are using a framework like angular you must declare some logic to work (angular 1.3+), for example.

You must create the main module of your app:

```
angular.module('yourmodule', [])  // the last parameter [] create the module, that array are the dependencies
```

With your module created you must attach the controller to the module, you have a function mainCtrl created, i'm gonna use it:

```
var module = angular.module('yourmodule')  // without the second argument, get the module with that name
module.controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl) // This assign the name mainCtrl the function mainCtrl
```

And finally, add to ng-app the module created:

```
  <html ng-app="yourmodule">
```

I hope this work, and welcome to angular world!!!

Comment: Really? I did not know. Thank you!!! (I edit the answer). But well anyone want start a project with an old version on angular 1.2, and most if the next week come the 1.4 version

Comment: But the current 1.3 is a stable one, and the writer of the question maybe don't have a production solution with the angular 1.2 (Maybe is learning the framework). And in the ng-conf mention not big break issue between 1.3 and 1.4. So start with the angular 1.3 is not a bad idea for later migrating to 1.4