# Angular stops working When i use ng-controller in the html tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in `Angular.js` and start learning angular on `plunker.co`. The problem is when I use `ng-controller` in any tag of `html` page , `angular` stops working. I mean `{{ 4+4 }}` display as it is just after the using of `ng-controller`.

**this is code from `Plunker.co`**

```
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" 
    src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    {{8*8}}
{{message}}

  </body>

</html>
```

without `ng-controller` it displays `64` as output but with `ng-controller` is displays as it is like `{{8*8}}`.  why it is happening. Please give some advice. thnks in advance. :)

**script.js**

```
var MainController = function($scope){
  $scope.message = "Hello World!";
}
```

**edited**
Now `message` attirbute value is not displaying on page.

Comment: ng-controller="yourControllerName" that defined in script.js. it is display as is because, it cause error and angular stop running.

Comment: but i tried this also. nothing is happing.

Comment: also ng-app="yourApp" name. and please link to plnkr. so can point out what is wrong. script.js should be like `angular.module('yourApp', []).controller('yourControllerName', function($scope) {})`

Comment: You are supposed to give `ng-controller` the name of your controller. Otherwise, it treats it as bad syntax. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$controller/ctrlfmt. In short either `ng-controller` = `"ControllerName"` or remove `ng-controller` altogether

Comment: @YOU It is possible to use ng-app as a directive. You don't need to specify the name of any app: http://jsfiddle.net/4xfq2xLu/1/, but if you set a controller as an attribute angular expects it to be named -> you can have multiple controllers, but only one app. Although I agree with you to name the app.

Comment: @YOU thanx. your advice works. But now  I am not getting the value of `message` attribute on html page.

Comment: have you considered just using the angular template that plunker provides?

it like...already works.  And you can see the proper way to set it up.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2

Comment: @sohail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111831/controller-not-a-function-got-undefined-while-defining-controllers-globally... In Angular 1.3+ it may not work... you cannot add controller to global scope

Comment: i was defining the controller in global scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First try to set a name for your app :

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

then set a name for your controller :

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
```

and finally, all you need to do is to define your app :

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

and try this definition for your controller :

```
myApp.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Hello World!";
});
```

Comment: a typo there, should be myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

Answer (score 1):

`ng-controller` expects a parameter that is the name of the controller defined in your angular code. Something like `ng-controller=foo`. You should [read up](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) more on how Controllers work

Comment: I updated my Question please check it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can use in the AngularJS controllers without name. Please set a name for your controller and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean it all works? http://jsfiddle.net/4xfq2xLu/2/

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    {{8*8}}
{{message}}  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var MainController = function($scope){
  $scope.message = "Hello World!";
}
```

Comment: on plunker its not working

Comment: [link]http://plnkr.co/edit/CjUKOsjgewgfBFTOM1rB?p=preview

Comment: Figured it out, must be an issue with the versions: Try loading 1.2.1 and it all works fine also with plunker.

Comment: issue resolved. I was defining the controller in global scope. .

Comment: Yes, but it was possible in earlier versions. fiddle stops also working with 1.3+ http://jsfiddle.net/4xfq2xLu/3/

Comment: yes @Mikey , i was seeing the old tutorials on youtube. In the tutorial he was using controller in global scope. so i was trying just like him.