# Sharing data between functions in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, scope

I am trying to implement two functions in an an angular app but as soon as I implement the filter (start with letters from to), the code stops working. On their own, the (add/delete) functions work but as soon as I turn the data into a factory and try to access with the filter functions it fails.

Working functions:

```
$scope.items = items;

$scope.deleteItem = function (index) {
    items.data.splice(index, 1);
}
$scope.addItem = function (index) {
    items.data.push({
        Name: $scope.newItemName
    });
}
```

What causes the whole thing to break:

```
//filtering letters _ NOT WORKING
    function setLetters (from, to){
        this.fromLetter = from;
        this.toLetter = to;
      }
    //----



$scope.filter.startsWithLetter = function () {
    return function (items, fromLetter, toLetter) {
        var filtered = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            var firstLetter = item.Name.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase();
            if ((!fromLetter || firstLetter >= fromLetter)
                && (!toLetter || firstLetter <= toLetter)) {
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        }
    return filtered;
   };
 });
```

//--filtering letters

Full code here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tupira/5dn2mtb8/424/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues in the fiddle. First I'm seeing an `"Unexpected token )"` error due to an extra `)` on line 58.

Then when I fix that there is an issue on line 45 as you are trying to assign a value to `$scope.filter.startsWithLetter`, when `$scope.filter` is undefined. I think you want to assign the value to `$scope.startsWithLetter`.

There is still a problem with the filtering. When filtering with `ng-repeat` you can specify a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) or simply [a predicate function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). In each case the arguments passed to the function will be different - please read the docs. The function as-is is designed to be used in a filter created with `angular.module('myApp', []).filter()`. It doesn't work when you set it on the scope and pass it to `filter:` as a predicate function. If you prefer to filter using a function on the scope, rather than creating a reusable custom filter, you need to change it to accept the correct arguments - see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/suu8o4a7/).

Your page is trying to access `setLetters` in `$scope.items.data` but you are not setting `$scope.items.data.setLetters`. I don't think it makes sense to set it there inside `items.data` anyway. Perhaps set it directly on the scope? I also would set `fromLetter` and `toLetter` directly on the scope.

I also moved the setLetter buttons inside a `<div ng-controller="ItemsController" >`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/suu8o4a7/) with those fixes

Comment: Hey Sheilak, many thanks for looking into this. Part of your answer is still unclear to me but the $scope.filter issue was definitely worth pointing out! Ideally what I want is to create a whole contacts factory service which I have begun to play with here http://jsfiddle.net/Tupira/5dn2mtb8/426/ but I am still having problems to get my controller accessing the factory service. But that is another thread.

Comment: Hi Sheilak, is there an issue with different versions of angularjs with your jsfiddle above? Whenver I add anything above angular 1.2 it throws an "https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=ItemsController&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined" error. What is causing this?

Comment: I fixed this with this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111831/controller-not-a-function-got-undefined-while-defining-controllers-globally by making sure to add myApp.controllerName to make it explicit. Jezz! Angularjs is not as intuitive as they make out.

Comment: It takes a while to get the hang of it :) glad you got sorted

Comment: No worries sheilak, thanks for your help. Is there a way to make the push function actually update the array itself? If you could point me into the right direction for this it would be great as once the page is reloaded, the array is back to the old results.

Comment: The push function does update the array itself, it adds the new items to the end of the array. But when you reload the page, the state is lost and when the page loads it will initialise the hardcoded array you have defined. If you want to persist changes to the array between page loads, you would need to start saving the data somewhere e.g. in a database.

Comment: That is what I thought! Thanks again Sheilak.