# Browser not able to parse AngularJS code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

I have written a simple program in AngularJS after including the minified angular JS in the script tag but the browser is not able to parse the angular JS code. I have other programs with more or less same code and they are working fine.

Am I missing/overlooking anything ?

**MVC Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>MVC Example</title>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function MyFirstCtrl($scope) {
                var employees = ['Catherine Grant', 'Monica Grant', 'Christopher Grant', 'Jennifer Grant'];
                $scope.ourEmployees = employees;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
        <body ng-controller='MyFirstCtrl'>
        <h2>Number of Employees: {{ourEmployees.length}}</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Browser Output:**

```
Number of Employees: {{ourEmployees.length}}
```

Comment: global functions no longer supported - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111831/controller-not-a-function-got-undefined-while-defining-controllers-globally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You  need to create a module to use with `ng-app`.

```
angular.module("foo", []);
angular.controller("MyFirstCtrl", MyFirstCtrl);

<html ng-app=foo>
```

Comment: @user2325154 the first two lines are in your JavaScript code or `<script>` tags. The last line is in your html

Comment: Perfect! Worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the app and add the controller in the right form:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('MyFirstCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var employees = ['Catherine Grant', 'Monica Grant', 'Christopher Grant', 'Jennifer Grant'];
    $scope.ourEmployees = employees;
}]);
<script>
```

Comment: I am using Angular JS version 1.2

Answer (score 0):

After some R&D I finally figured out solution for both v1.2 and v1.3+

**v1.2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app=foo>
    <head>
        <title>MVC Example</title>
        <script src="js/angular.min-1.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            angular.module("foo", []);
            angular.controller("MyFirstCtrl", MyFirstCtrl);

            var employees = ['Catherine Grant', 'Monica Grant', 'Christopher Grant', 'Jennifer Grant'];

            function MyFirstCtrl($scope) {
                var employees = ['Catherine Grant', 'Monica Grant', 'Christopher Grant', 'Jennifer Grant'];
                $scope.ourEmployees = employees;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
        <body ng-controller='MyFirstCtrl'>
        <h2>Number of Employees: {{ourEmployees.length}}</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

**v1.3+ Onwards**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app=foo>
    <head>
        <title>MVC Example</title>
        <script src="js/angular.min-1.4.js"></script>
        <script>
            var employees = ['Catherine Grant', 'Monica Grant', 'Christopher Grant', 'Jennifer Grant'];
            var foo = angular.module("foo", []);
            foo.controller("MyFirstCtrl", function ($scope) {
                $scope.ourEmployees = employees;
            });
        </script>
    </head>
        <body ng-controller='MyFirstCtrl'>
        <h2>Number of Employees: {{ourEmployees.length}}</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```