# How to define AngularJS controller in HTML Template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following structure of files:

- index.html
- tpl/page.html
- app.js

Description:

1. app.js has definition of main module with routing to page.html
2. index.html defines view for template and includes app.js
3. page.html has definition of PageController inside `<script>` tag and div who is using this controller.

**Problem**
When PageController resides in page.html it doesn't work but when it is included into app.js then it works. Error is following: Argument 'PageController' is not aNaNunction, got undefined.

It looks like it is too late to define controller in template. But actually it is my requirement. I want to hide page.html + controller (even their code) from all users and make it visible only to particular group by Spring security. That is why I defined security constraint for this page and want it to be executed only when this constraints are met.

**Update #1** Controller definition:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  mainApp.controller('PageController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    ...
  });
</script>

<md-content ng-controller="PageController" ...
```

Comment: Please show an example of how you are defining the controller in the template.

Comment: Done. Controller definition added.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111831/controller-not-a-function-got-undefined-while-defining-controllers-globally) out

Answer (score 0):

If both the script tag and the HTML for the template are defined in an external html file, Angular should complain and say that you cannot have two root elements in a template file.

My suggestion would be to have your controller in a separate JS file and set your Spring Security permissions on that. If you are using JSPs or something similar to render the main page, you could then add a conditional around the `<script>` tag for the controller if the user has access.

Comment: Could be an option but I have token mechanism of authorization so I need to intercept somehow browser's request to this JS file. And moreover since this it is a single page application and first unauthorized request will not provide token (when you just enter a page). But after authorization JS will not be requested again because I think you are proposing to include it into index page.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was proposing.  I have no experience dynamically loading controllers like what you are wanting.  The application I work on is more of a 2-page app.  One for the public stuff and one for the protected stuff.  Good luck on working it out.