# Angular js controller not registered

Tags: angularjs

i am new in angularjs and nodejs, What i am doing is create a html file name of index.html and make a controller.js file in which printing a console.log message but getting error on browser in console box my code is as follow

```
<html ng-app>

 <head>
 <title> App </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```
 <body>
     <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <h1> Contact List App </h1>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td> name </td>
                <td> Email </td>
                <td> mobile </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
```

and controller.js code is as follow

```
 function AppCtrl() {
  console.log("Hello Bro")
                 }
```

Comment: You haven't declared a top-level module to set `ng-app=(module)`. You need to create that module then you can define your controller based off that module. (i.e. `angular.module('myTopLevelModule').controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);`

Comment: I see: No reference to angular.js, to your main module. Also there is no registration of your controller in your code file, just a function. I recommend you find a tutorial and do that first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controller not a function, got undefined, while defining controllers globally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111831/controller-not-a-function-got-undefined-while-defining-controllers-globally)

Comment: i saw a video in which a coder done exactly what i write but his code works successfully.

Comment: Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=AppCtrl
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:10835
    at ba (angular.js:9924)
    at n (angular.js:9694)
    at g (angular.js:9048)
    at g (angular.js:9051)
    at g (angular.js:9051)
    at angular.js:8913
    at angular.js:1914
    at m.$eval (angular.js:18172)

Comment: this error is generating in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you cannot call this a Angular App.

You dont have the **`module`**. Declare a module as follows,

```
 var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);
```

Register a controller,

```
app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
      function($scope) {
}
```

You have not refered the angular **`reference`**.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);
app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    console.log("Hello Bro");
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
<head>
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="dobController">
  <div class="col-md-20">
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank You Bro your save my time :)