# How to display json file data in html using angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

get_student_details.json

```
{
    "student": [
       {
           "studentname": "MANNAT SACHDEVA",
           "Class": "3",
           "percentage": "96",
           "student_answer": [
                {
                    "1": "C",
                    "2": "A"
                }
           ],
            "correct_answer": [
                {
                    "1": "C",
                    "2": "A"
                }
            ]
       }
   ]
}
```

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function studentController($scope, $http) {
                var url = "http://localhost/olm/get_student_details.json";
                $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
                    $scope.student_details = response;
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="container" id="whole-page">
        <div class="col-lg-12" id="box">
            <div ng-app="" ng-controller="studentController">
                <div ng-repeat="detail in student_details">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h3>Student Name</h3>
                                <h1 style="color: rgb(19, 191, 255);">{{ detail.studentname }}</h1>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <h3>Class</h3>
                                <h1>{{ detail.class }}</h1>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h3 id="left" style="margin-top:60px;">PERCENTAGE</h3>
                                <div id="right">
                                    <h2 id="percent">{{ detail.percent }}%</h2>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table style="margin-top:15px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <ol id = "limheight">
                                    <li>1 - {{ detail.student_answer }} <span id="ans">{{ detail.correct_answer }}</span></li>
                                </ol> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new in angular js and I want to display json file data i.e. get_student_details.json into index.html file. Now I have create a funtion to insert json data into index.html after that when I reload index.php nothing happen it remain same I don't know where I am doing wrong. So, How can I fix this issue ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: you firstly need to parse API as per Key value params you require in two way binding in Angular View HTML

Comment: Are you getting any data in console.log from the AP? I recommend using relative paths to your file...

 function studentController($scope, $http) {
                var url = "olm/get_student_details.json";
                $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
                    $scope.student_details = response;
                });
            }

Comment: nothing are showing @JoshLavely

Comment: Suggest you learn how to register controllers properly. The angular version you are using is very old and you are going to run into problems due to more current approaches used See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111831/controller-not-a-function-got-undefined-while-defining-controllers-globally

Comment: Also suggest you go through the tutorial on the documentation site https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: And you want to iterate the array which is in your `student` property  `ng-repeat="detail in student_details.student"`